# How to check if a row meets multiple conditions? (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel file like below:

[image: Excel screenshot]

I have a list of metrics that falls into either 2 categories (Priority 1 and Priority 2).Then I have a list of reports (row) that contain some metrics.

How do I check which rows ('Reports') have a TRUE for **both** Priority 1 and Priority 2?

For example: Report A has Metric A and Metric C. Metric A is in Priority 1 and Metric C is in priority 2. So Report A meets the condition.

On the other hand, Report D has Metric A and Metric B. Both Metrics A and B are in Priority 1. Since Report D does not have a metric that belongs in Priority 2 so Report D does not meet the condition.

I have over 700 reports and 30 metrics to check but I believe I should still be able to do this using an excel formula, but I'm open to doing this through other methods (Python, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Use SUMPRODUCTS to "count" how many are `TRUE` in the REPORT AND `YES` in the Metric(one for each Metric).  Then multiply the two checks.

```
=(SUMPRODUCT(B5:E5*($B$2:$E$2="YES"))>0)*(SUMPRODUCT(B5:E5*($B$3:$E$3="YES"))>0)>0
```

[image]

---

Another option that does not require the use of 30 SUMPRODUCTS(one for each of your Metrics)

We can use MMULT and MATCH to ensure that every Metric is used:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH(ROW($B$2:$E$3),MMULT(TRANSPOSE(($B$2:$E$3="YES")*B5:E5),ROW($B$2:$E$3)),0)))
```

The MMULT basically creates a vertical array of row numbers of the Metrics where the Metric is `YES` and the Report is `TRUE`.  Then the MATCH rolls through each row of Metrics and sees if that row number exists in the returned array.  With AND all row numbers of the Metrics must be in the array to return a `TRUE` response.

Depending on One's version this may need to be entered with ctrl-shift-enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image: ![enter image description here]